# Lights/emission not showing through glass

Tags: shaders, transparency, lighting, glass, emission

I have copied this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W0S-ZP1ws-Y) for transparent glass at 6:17 - 7:04, and for emission/light, 10:30 - 10:50.

As you can see from the following screebshots, I copied these transparent glass and emission settings from that tutorial, yet this is what came out:

Glass BSDF from one angle [image]
Glass BSDF from another angle: [image]

Emission sphere settings:[image]

I also flipped all normals outside, for the cube and sphere. How do I view the emission shining through the glass from any angle? Thanks

File:
[image]

Comment: I often have the same problem, that in some angles (in my case it seems to be that when the viewpoint is slightly below the light's origin so that you are looking up to the light) the light bulb disappears. Since it's very predictable for me I wonder if this is simply some kind of limitation of _Eevee_ or the _Alpha Blend_ mode in general. I prefer _Cycles_ anyway...

Comment: Okay, I found something out - nothing to give a solution, but a kind of rule to when the sphere disappears: whenever the origin point of the sphere lies behind the origin of the cube (i.e. further away in Z depth), the sphere becomes invisible. If it is closer to your viewpoint or the camera from which you are viewing it, it reappears. If both origins are in the same location, the sphere stays completely invisible. So it seems like this really is just the way _Alpha Blend_ in _Eevee_ works...

Answer (score 0):

Your light needs to be *Opaque*, it is currently set to *Alpha Blend*, Eevee has problem to show an *Alpha Blend* object (or an object with *Screen Space Refraction*) through another *Alpha Blend* object:

[image]

See from 13:37 to 13:45, he also has transparency problems, and to fix it he mixes his *Glass* with a *Transparent* node, also I'm not sure why he makes the light bulb *Alpha Blend* as it is supposed to be an opaque object:

[image]

Comment: Good answer, but in the video tutorial i mentioned, he did this: https://i.ibb.co/Sw0QMGb/posture.jpg, and notice here https://i.ibb.co/DCF2M6F/posture.jpg the engine is in Eevee? How did he make the emission here visible through the glass regardless of angle?

Comment: I've edited my answer

Comment: I see, makes sense. Sorry for a stupid question, but how did he mix his Glass with a Transparent node? When and where did he do so?

Comment: See at 14:30......

Comment: Maybe he uses _Alpha Blend_ in the tutorial for the light bulb, because since he didn't enable _Screen Space Refraction_ on the glass material, his bulb is not visible unless he enables _Alpha Blend_ there as well. Not the first time that I see a Youtube tutorial where the tutor doesn't really know what he is doing.  ;)

Comment: @moonbots, I tried 14:30. While I can now see the glow on all sides, unfortunately, the glow is stronger from some angles, and weaker from others: https://ibb.co/VwtWvrj, https://ibb.co/dDgJN4m. I'd like the glow to be equal on all sides. Thanks

Comment: Did you switch the light to Opaque? What glow are you talking about, are you using Bloom? Maybe share your current file?

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann oh ok yes that's not correct

Comment: @moonboots here is the current file https://blend-exchange.com/b/gzGqdeD9. No, for the glow I didn't switch to Opaque, it's still at Alpha Blend under Blend Mode, and Opaque for shadow mode.

Comment: You should switch the bulb to Opaque, as I said you can't see correctly an alpha blend object behind another one, so I guess the Bloom problem comes from that as well

Comment: @moonboots, Thanks, I'll do as you suggested